# Is there any way to display the label inside on bar in column chart in C#

Tags: c#

Is there any way to display the label inside on bar in column chart in C#

Please find the sample code below.

```
private void LoadChartData2(DataTable dt)
{
    DataTable dtMon = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Month");
    foreach (DataRow drMon in dtMon.Rows)
    {
        Series series = new Series();
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select(string.Concat("Month='", drMon.ItemArray[0].ToString(), "'")))
        {
            String ses = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            switch (ses.Trim())
            {
                case "Platinum":

                    series.Points.AddXY("Platinum", dr.ItemArray[2]);

                    if (Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()) >= 99.00M)
                    {
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderWidth = 2;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].ToolTip = "Percentage: #VALY\n Month: "+ dr.ItemArray[1];
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Url = "~/Detailed_report.aspx";
                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()) >= 94.00M && Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()) < 99.00M)
                    {
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFC200");
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderWidth = 2;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].ToolTip = "Percentage: #VALY\n Month: " + dr.ItemArray[1];
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Url="~/Detailed_report.aspx";
                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()) < 94.00M)
                    {
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderWidth = 2;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].ToolTip = "Percentage: #VALY\n Month: " + dr.ItemArray[1];
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Url = "~/Detailed_report.aspx";
                    }

                    break;
                case "Gold":
                    series.Points.AddXY("Gold", dr.ItemArray[2]);

                    if (Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()) >= 98.00M)
                    {
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderWidth = 2;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].ToolTip = "Percentage: #VALY\n Month: " + dr.ItemArray[1];
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Url = "~/Detailed_report.aspx";


                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()) >= 93.00M && Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()) < 98.00M)
                    {
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFC200");
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderWidth = 2;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].ToolTip = "Percentage: #VALY\n Month: " + dr.ItemArray[1];
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Url = "~/Detailed_report.aspx";
                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()) < 93.00M)
                    {
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderWidth = 2;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].ToolTip = "Percentage: #VALY\n Month: " + dr.ItemArray[1];
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Url = "~/Detailed_report.aspx";
                    }
                    break;

                case "Silver":
                    series.Points.AddXY("Silver", dr.ItemArray[2]);

                    if (Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()) >= 95.00M)
                    {
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderWidth = 2;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].ToolTip = "Percentage: #VALY\n Month: " + dr.ItemArray[1];
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Url = "~/Detailed_report.aspx";


                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()) >= 90.00M && Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()) < 95.00M)
                    {
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFC200");
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderWidth = 2;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].ToolTip = "Percentage: #VALY\n Month: " + dr.ItemArray[1];
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Url = "~/Detailed_report.aspx";



                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()) < 90.00M)
                    {
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].BorderWidth = 2;
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].ToolTip = "Percentage: #VALY\n Month: " + dr.ItemArray[1];
                        series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Url = "~/Detailed_report.aspx";
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        Chart2.Series.Add(series);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a very long snippet. Would you mind replacing it with a smaller example?

Answer (score 6):

You can use this to show the Label at the top but inside the columns:

```
    Series S1 = chart1.Series[0];
    S1.Label = "#VALY";
    S1.LabelForeColor = Color.White;
    S1["LabelStyle"] = "Bottom";
```

Note that `Bottom` means: Below the `Y-Value of the DataPoint`. See MSDN on the [LabelAlignmentStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.labelalignmentstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

See here for the result:

[image]

Update: Note that one can set both colors and alignment for indiviual DataPoints as well!