# DataVisualization Charting - Place Point Label In Bar (If Go Outside Of Chart)

Tags: c#

I am using DataVisualization.Charting in C# to generate a column chart - The issue I am having is that the label I am adding to show the value of the bar is displaying off the top of the chart (See image below).

The 0 values are ok but in a perfect world in the scenario below I would like the label on the columns with data which go off the top of the chart to be placed within the bar its self - Is this possible at all?

I have tried various settings via the Series SmartLabelStyles but have not been able to find a solution which works.

Below is how I am adding my labels to the chart:

```
chart.Series[0].Points[0].Label = Math.Round(pos1, 2).ToString() + "hrs " + Math.Round(((pos1 / totalHoursV) * 100), 2).ToString() + "%";
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have tried to display the Labels on the Bottom as per this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28590709/2822664) which does actually work for the values in the bars and shows the values in the bar, however it then messes up the values of 0 and doesn't show them correctly (See image below).

[image]

Comment: _a bar chart_ Acutally this is a Column chart. - To change the label placement you can use LabelStyle = Bottom. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588325/is-there-any-way-to-display-the-label-inside-on-bar-in-column-chart-in-c-sharp/28590709#28590709)

Comment: @Taw please see update, I have found your answer to a previous question like this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588325/is-there-any-way-to-display-the-label-inside-on-bar-in-column-chart-in-c-sharp?rq=1) however this doesn't work for the 0 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the **alignment** of the `Labels` by setting a [custom property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd456764(v=vs.140)).

This can be done for the whole `Series` but also for each `DataPoint` **individually**:

```
Series s = chart1.Series[0];
s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
s.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    int p = s.Points.AddXY(i, rnd.Next(30));
    DataPoint pt = s.Points[p];
    if (pt.YValues[0] >   10)   // use a suitable value!
    {
       pt.SetCustomProperty("LabelStyle", "Bottom");
       pt.LabelForeColor = Color.White;
    }
    else pt.LabelBackColor = Color.White;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - I did think this might be possible after trying your answer on the other question. I have implemented a crude version and it has worked, I think ill just need to tweak the values in the future as I have to manaually calculate if to display the label above the column or in the column based on the min/max values on an individual chart basis - I was hoping there would be a simple built in solution